# If I use repeated cross-sectional data in a DiD setting, what are the conditions required for my study to be causal?

Tags: causality, difference-in-difference

I am new to statistics and I want to explore the impact of a specific policy reform. The treatment year is 2014, and I have 7 waves of post-treatment surveys along with 9 waves of pre-treatment surveys. Although I have all the relevant variables for my study, my data is cross-sectional rather than longitudinal.

I am focusing on determining the causal effect of the reform on my dependent variable Y. What conditions must my groups meet for me to interpret my results as "causal"?